# See the score of each fold when cross validating a model using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, cross-validation

I want to see the individual score of each fitted model to visualize the strength of cross validation (I am doing this to show my coworkers why cross validation is important).

I have a .csv file with 500 rows, 200 independent variables and 1 binary target. I defined `skf` to fold the data 5 times using `StratifiedKFold`.

My code looks like this:

```
X = data.iloc[0:500, 2:202]
y = data["target"]
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, random_state = 0)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel = "linear")
Scores = [0] * 5
for i, j in skf.split(X, y):
    X_train, y_train = X.iloc[i], y.iloc[i]
    X_test, y_test = X.iloc[j], y.iloc[j]
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

As you can see, I assigned a list of 5 zeroes to `Scores`. I would like to assign the `clf.score(X_test, y_test)` of each of the 5 predictions to the list. However, the indices `i` and `j` are not {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. Rather, they are row numbers used to fold the `X` and `y` data frames.

How can I assign the test scores of each of the `k` fitted models into `Scores`within this loop? Do I need a separate index for this?

I know using `cross_val_score` literally does all this and gives you a geometric average of the `k` scores. However, I want to show my coworkers what happens behind the cross validation functions that come in the `sklearn` library.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question, and you don't need any particular indexing for Scores:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X = np.random.normal(size = (500, 200))
y = np.random.randint(low = 0, high=2, size=500)
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, random_state = 0)
clf = SVC(kernel = "linear")
Scores = []
for i, j in skf.split(X, y):
    X_train, y_train = X[i], y[i]
    X_test, y_test = X[j], y[j]
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    Scores.append(clf.score(X_test, y_test))
```

The result is:

```
>>>Scores
[0.5247524752475248, 0.53, 0.5, 0.51, 0.4444444444444444]
```

Comment: You understood the question correctly. This solved my problem. I always forget the existance of the `append` method in Python.